# How to sum only matched key value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm using following dataframe in R.

DF<-

```
ID        Date                   Notes                    Value
PR-1      2020-01-25 15:13:17    avbc  sdr df/ert  123    1500.00
PR-1      2020-01-25 15:13:17    avbc  sdr df/ert  123    25000.00
PR-1      2020-01-25 15:13:17    Successful Trn to A/c    10000.00
PR-1      2020-01-25 15:13:17    Successful Trn to A/c    15000.00
PR-1      2020-01-25 15:13:17    avbc  sdr df/ert  123    5000.00
PR-2      2020-01-20 22:33:45    xyzs  sdr df/ert  123    [null]
PR-2      2020-01-20 22:33:45    avbc  ert df/ert  123    0.00
PR-2      2020-01-20 22:33:45    Successful Trn to A/c    15000.00
PR-2      2020-01-20 22:33:45    Successful Trn to A/c    25000.00
PR-2      2020-01-20 22:33:45    Successful Trn to A/c    15000.00
PR-2      2020-01-20 22:33:45    aerc  sxr df/ert  123    
PR-3      2020-01-12 19:12:34    aerc  sxr df/ert  123    1400.00
```

I want to sum the value where the 'Notes' contains string like `Successful Trn to A/c`.

Request Output:

```
ID        Date                      Sum_Value     Status
PR-1      2020-01-25 15:13:17       25000.00      False 
PR-2      2020-01-20 22:33:45       55000.00      True
PR-3      2020-01-12 19:12:34       0             No String
```

If the `Sum_Value` is >=50000 than True or False and if the no entry with `Successful Trn to A/c` is available than `No String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>% filter(str_detect(Notes, "Successful")) %>% group_by(ID, Date) %>%
summarise(Sum_value = sum(Value))
```

PS: Please post the data next time with `dput(data)`.